# Linux OSI equivalent to Winsock2's LSP

Tags: linux, tcp, firewall

I'm looking for Linux's OSI equivalent to Windows' winsock2 LSP.

In particular I would like to filter application layer protocols and traffic in linux.

Any information would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what Winsock2 LSP does, it's difficult to answer your question.

1. You can implement application-layer protocols with the appropriate packet(7) socket. Read the man page for more information
2. If you want to do network filtering in userspace, you can use the netfilter_queue facility, typically combined with iptables NFQUEUE target rules. You can use this to selectively filter particular types of traffic through a userspace daemon.

I hope this helps.